# How to map getBody array list response of RestTemplate into class in Spring boot?

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I've used restTemplate to get the details from a third party API.

Where, below code give me a response in string (using response.getBody())

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Example of JSON

```
{"Entries":[{"EntryId":"1","Field1":"1","Field2":"2"},{"EntryId":"2","Field1":"3","Field2":"4"}]}
```

I've also created a class called Entries,

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Entries {

    @JsonProperty("EntryId")
    private String entryId;

    @JsonProperty("Field1")
    private String field1;

    @JsonProperty("Field2")
    private String field2;

//getter and setters
```

Is there any way to map JSON Array with Entires class using RestTemplate?

Comment: I think `restTemplate.getForEntity(resourceUrl, Entity.class);`

Comment: @fg78nc Actually I've to pass some header params. So, I've used `restTemplate.exchange()`. I've just found a solution and which is posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways,

[1] Using ObjectMapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Entries obj = mapper.readValue(rrateResponse.getBody(), Entries.class);
```

[2] Passing an Entries class

```
ResponseEntity<Entries> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Entries.class);
```

The only missing thing was an Entries which is mentioned below.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Entries {

    @JsonProperty("Entries")
    private List<Entry> Entries;

//getter and setter
```